# Allow me to disable or remove "Discover Stack Overflow Careers" button

Tags: feature-request, jobs, profile-page

Even if I didn't have a Stack Overflow Careers account, please note I already **do**, I should be allowed to remove / hide the "Discover Stack Overflow Careers" link in my profile.

For instance, I've already "discovered" it, why does it stick there if I:

1. Already discovered it
2. Already have an account there telling the system I know you exist

Please don't push careers so much on people, I think you should do a simple check:

```
if (user is already registered with careers)
   bigOrangeCareersButton.Visible=false;
else
   bigOrangeCareersButton.Visible=true;
```

There's the button I'm talking about:

> [image: profile page]

Answer (score -2):

[Once you disabled the public button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259786), this button ("Discover Stack Overflow Careers") is the *private one, seen only by you*; I can't see it:

> [image]

Still, if it is annoying (as for me, I didn't even notice it), [install this user script](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/10729-no-careers) and stop seeing it.

Comment: Sorry installing a user script I dont believe is a fix for this.  I truly believe this is a bug.  I'm already a careers users - what exactly am I discovering?

Comment: @Jon Your aim is ... ?

Comment: My aim is that I do not consider this an answer, just an option (maybe you can post it as a comment).  A user script doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @JonH I've flagged your comment as `not constructive`. Shall we take ourselves seriously?

Comment: @Jon I'm not harassing you, but trying to express common sense.