# Why 2 links to the same thing so close to each other

Tags: support, jobs

I don't see any purpose of having careers links twice, within the same page and so close to each other.

We already have the link twice within our profile:

> [image]

Also, there's no need in this big orange button.  Just as you have one link to github and not a secondary button GITHUB, even if Stack Overflow owns Careers.

Answer (score 6):

The first link is the career profile; the user can select it in their profile editor and choose whether it's shown or not.

The second link is the link to *website* the user specifies themselves. In this case, the user decided to specify their website as their career profile.

> [image]

You can remove the website link by editing out the "website link" field and disable "Stack Overflow Careers Profile" link by unchecking the checkbox "Show Careers link on my profile".

Comment: I dont buy it, for me they go to the same page.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: But if I disable the link, I still have the orange button, I don't care to see the orange button, if its enabled they both show?

Comment: @Jon **The second link is the link to website the user specifies themselves**. It can be the career profile or whatever. example.com would go to.

Comment: Okay maybe I did this incorrectly and you probably are right, why does the orange button have to be there though?  Most individuals either know about it and are already use it or don't care.  It seems to me like rubbish advertising.

Comment: Right I fixed that I see I had placed careers initially there, not sure why I did that!

Comment: @Jon maybe my edit would also clarify something.

Comment: Right but if I disable the orange button I am presented with a "Discover Stack Overflow Careers" - Im not interested because I've already discovered it...so why should I "re-discover" it?

Comment: This all comes back to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254664/allow-me-to-disable-or-remove-discover-stack-overflow-careers

Comment: @Jon **disable "Stack Overflow Careers Profile" link by unchecking the checkbox "Show Careers link on my profile**.

Comment: right but then It overrides that button with a "Discover Careers link..." see my post http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254664/allow-me-to-disable-or-remove-discover-stack-overflow-careers

Comment: @Jon What? If you uncheck that checkbox, you get shown "Discover Stack Overflow Careers?"

Comment: Yes see my screen print in the other post.

Comment: go back to your profile you don't see the link ?

Comment: @Jon http://i.stack.imgur.com/9tXtM.png

Comment: but that isn't your so profile that is your se profile no ?

Comment: @Jon Wait, I can see this on my SO profile.

Comment: lol nicael, that is my point...I'd rather not "discover" so careers, as I'm already a member of careers - now you see what I see.

Comment: @Jon So again, what do you want?

Comment: I'd rather not see career related advertising on my profile - I feel this is a form of it...even if they leave it they should not show it for members of careers.  I'm already registered with careers so what exactly am i discovering?

Comment: @Jon You realize that only you can see this link?

Comment: @Jon OK, wait a bit. This question seems to be solved, right?

Comment: Right but as I said, I'm already registered with careers, what exactly am I discovering?  I don't care to discover something I've already discovered.  There's enough proof that the world is already round, I'm not going to rediscover that based on the evidence.

Comment: No - well sort of - I guess we can close as dupe to my other question.  Status "STILL NOT RESOLVED".

Comment: @Jon WTF? How is it a dupe of your previous question?

Comment: @Jon This question **is solved, isn't it?** I explained you the reason of the dupe links, didn't I?

Comment: nicael - did you read my previous post.  I want to be able to remove the fact that I do not WANT TO DISCOVER CAREERS...I've already discovered it!

Comment: That is why I voted to close AS DUPE because the issue goes back to my linked post.

Comment: @Jon ... it doesn't. The link  "discover" only can be seen by you. If you want to remove the public SO careers button, please reread my post. If you want to stop seeing "discover" button, write a user script. Nobody else does see "discover" on your profile.

Comment: I already found how to remove the button, again see my edit in my post.  I've already realized that and gave you +1 for it.

Comment: @Jon That's a completely different issue and is not related to the current question in any way. The public button can be removed with one click, the "discover" button can be seen only by you. It's not public.

Comment: @Jon, also, I answered your previous question and hope you understand it.